# Is there any evidence that Daniel rejected Nebuchadnezzar's worship in Daniel 2?

Tags: daniel, christology, attributes-of-god

> 45Forasmuch as thou sawest that the stone was cut out of the mountain without hands, and that it brake in pieces the iron, the brass, the clay, the silver, and the gold; the great God hath made known to the king what shall come to pass hereafter: and the dream is certain, and the interpretation thereof sure.
>   46¶Then the king Nebuchadnezzar fell upon his face, and worshipped Daniel, and commanded that they should offer an oblation and sweet odours unto him.
>   47The king answered unto Daniel, and said, Of a truth it is, that your God is a God of gods, and a Lord of kings, and a revealer of secrets, seeing thou couldest reveal this secret. — (Daniel 2:45-47, KJV)

Is there anything in this passage, or in the greater context, to suggest that Daniel rejected this worship of Nebuchadnezzar?

(I understand that it is indicated that Nebuchadnezzar "answered" Daniel, and some have taken this to mean that Daniel said something to him which was not recorded; however, I believe that this goes against a natural reading of the text, as it seems like Nebuchadnezzar was responding to the prophecy which Daniel had just told him.)

In addition to this, if Daniel did not object to this worship, could it then be argued that Christ's acceptance of worship did not indicate that he believed that He was God? I am aware, of course, of other indications that Christ believed that He was God.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say 'it goes against a _natural_ reading' to state the obvious - that Daniel's rejection is unrecorded ? There is nothing unnatural about it, that I can see.

Comment: Verse 47 should suffice to answer your concern about verse 46. As for Christ, the difference should be obvious (John 20:28).

Comment: @NigelJ It seems unnatural to me because Nebuchadnezzar had not said anything to Daniel before that. Thus, I find it more likely that Nebuchadnezzar was responding to the prophecy that Daniel had just finished making. Howevet, after reading the text again, I can certainly accept the possibility that Nebuchadnezzar was answering something Daniel said which was not recorded, especially since the text does not have a conjunction before verse 47, which breaks it off from the preceding text.

Comment: @Lucian If Nebuchadnezzar was actually worshipping Daniel, then it is possible that he believed that Daniel was a lesser god. However, I am not concerning with Nebuchadnezzar's belief, but with Daniel's reaction to the worship. I do agree that the event which takes place between Christ and Saint Thomas in John 20 is clear evidence that Christ believed that He was God. However, I am more concerned with passages such as that in John 9, for example, when the man who was born blind worshipped Christ after He told him that He was the Son of God.

Comment: @CMK If Daniel wrote the book - and I have no doubt that he did, from the content - then it is Daniel who chooses not to report his own response to the Highest Majestic Authority on earth (at the time). He chooses to veil his own rebuke or corrective comment and he merely documents the King's response. I see nothing problematical about this. It is straightforward to me.

Comment: @NigelJ Are you suggesting that Daniel might have rebuked Nebuchadnezzar but didn't record the rebuke in order to avoid embarrassing the king? If so, that's actually a really interesting theory! :)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Yes, indeed. I think that to be the case. It makes sense. He is being subject to the King and not leaving his place. Thus he records the King's correction of the KIng's error, but does not record his own part in the correction of the King.

Comment: @NigelJ That does make sense of why Daniel did not record his rebuke, but this alone cannot substantiate the idea that Daniel did, in fact, rebuke Nebuchadnezzar. It is possible, though, that the lack of a conjunction in verse 47 indicates that certain events took place whuch are not recorded.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Did Nebuchadnezzar *really* "worship" Daniel? (Yes)**

Before answering your question, one must ask whether or not Nebuchadnezzar actually "worshipped" Daniel at all. Other translations say instead that he "paid homage to Daniel" or "paid him honor."

Daniel 2:46 uses the Aramaic word סְגִד, meaning "do homage (by prostration)" according to [Brown-Driver-Briggs](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/5457.htm).

> **Prostration/Bowing-down-Honor/Homage doesn't automatically imply divine worship**
>
> (Genesis 23:12) "And Abraham **bowed down himself** before the people of the land."
>
> (Genesis 43:26) "And when Joseph came home, they brought him the present which was in their hand into the house, and **bowed themselves to him to the earth**."
>
> (1 Samuel 24:8) "David also arose afterward, and went out of the cave, and cried after Saul, saying, My lord the king. And when Saul looked behind him, David **stooped with his face to the earth**, and **bowed himself**."

Was Abraham worshiping the Canaanites? Were Joseph's brother's worshiping Joseph? Was David worshiping Samuel? I don't think so.

But was Nebuchadnezzar worshiping Daniel? The answer I give is **yes**. Here's why.

- On one hand, the definition which Brown-Driver-Briggs gives for סְגִד
  isn't strong enough to necessarily imply worship. So one might be tempted to think Nebuchadnezzar was just prostrating himself to Daniel as a sign of humility, just as David prostrated himself to Saul.
- Notice also that Nebuchadnezzar doesn't proclaim Daniel to be a god, but instead proclaims the God of Israel to be "a God of gods."
- On the other hand, Nebuchadnezzar was a pagan at the time rather than a God-fearing man like Abraham or David, so maybe he did really worship Daniel.
- Also, all other occurences of the Aramaic word סְגִד in the Hebrew Bible (it only appears in Daniel) are used in the context of idolatry, except in one case where it is used in reference to worship of the One True God.
- The Hebrew equivalent, סָגַד, appears 5 times in the Hebrew Bible (it only appears in Isaiah) and always in the context of idolatry. The non-idolatrous examples I have given earlier use different verbs.
- But Nebuchadnezzar definitely goes too far by commanding his men to **offer sacrifice of victims and incense to Daniel**.
- Although Abraham bowed down before the people of the land, he **didn't offer sacrifice of victims and incense to the Canaanites**.
- Although David "stooped with his face to the earth and bowed himself" to King Saul, he **didn't offer sacrifice of victims and incense to Saul**.

The fact that Nebuchadnezzar commands that sacrifice be offered to Daniel is the main reason why I believe that he really did worship Daniel, or at least intended to worship him.

---

**2. Did Daniel accept Nebuchadnezzer's worship? (Probably not)**

Even though there is sufficient reason to believe that Nebuchadnezzar actually did worship Daniel, it would be rash to conclude that Daniel in turn accepted the worship.

- Just because the text doesn't explicitly say that Daniel rejected the worship doesn't mean he didn't. The text doesn't say he accepted it either.
- Daniel and his three companions scrupulously followed the commandments of God, desperately going out their way in Chapter 1 to avoid eating unclean meats against the Law of Moses.
- Notice that Nebuchadnezzar "**commanded**" that sacrifice should be offered to Daniel. The text doesn't say that sacrifice was **actually** offered to Daniel. For all we know, maybe Daniel convinced Nebuchadnezzar not to do it.
- Given that Daniel was, at this point in the story, highly respected by Nebuchadnezzar as a great prophet, **surely Nebuchadnezzar would have listened to Daniel's request if Daniel told him not to offer sacrifice to him**.
- Daniel's request that his three companions be promoted is granted. (Daniel 2:49)
- Why would Nebuchadnezzar accept one request but not the other?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's probably about as much as an answer can be given on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous places where people paid honour to other humans by falling prostrate without this being interpreted as an act of worship.  Here are a few cases:

- Gen 23:7 - Abraham prostrates before the Hittites
- Gen 27:29 - Isaac prophesies that many nations will prostrate themselves before Jacob's descendants
- Gen 33:3 - Jacob prostrates himself seven times before Esau
- 1 Sam 24:8 - David prostrates himself before King Saul
- 2 Sam 19:18 - Shemei falls prostrate before King David

Thus, prostration was not necessarily an act of worship but to show honour (it was common eastern custom); however, worship was almost always accompanied by prostration as a means of honouring God.

Therefore, Nebuchadnezzar's prostration was not worship but a display and recognition of honour.  It is unfortunate that the KJV uses the verb "worshipped" rather than the more sensitive "honoured" or similar.

There is further circumstantial evidence of this conclusion:

- Before Daniel begins his explanation he gives all the honour to God (Dan 2:28)
- The first thing that Nebuchadnezzar says after the conclusion of Daniel's interpretation is not how great Daniel is but rather how great Daniel's God is (Dan 2:47).

Thus, Daniel was honoured, not as a God, but a representative of the one true God which the King recognised.  (Compare the status of an ambassador of a government today.)

Comment: "_and worshipped Daniel, and commanded that they should offer an oblation and sweet odours unto him_" does not sound like a mere 'paying honour to humans' to me, I have to say.

Comment: Your comment is obviously correct so I have expanded my answer.

Comment: Commentators agree that the word translated as worship here (segad, if I remember properly) speaks of worship offered to idols. Nebuchadnezzar, after worshipping Daniel, commanded that a sacrifice be made to him, as Nigel said. This is not merely paying honor to Daniel, although I wish it was. It seems like Nebuchadnezzar recognized Daniel as a god, and Daniel God as a God.

Comment: Please try not to read the Bible from modern times but the way it was understood at the time.  It is true that the word the KJV translates as worship is used for idols in some cases.  It is also used of honour and so cannot be decisive.  It was a common custom at the time for BOTH gods and highly honoured guests.  Nebuchadnezzar did NOT say Daniel was god but said that Daniel's God was supreme. Please do not venture beyond what the Bible actually says.

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan The standard usage of the word, that is of worship to idols, is substantiated by the fact that Nebuchadnezzar commands his men to make sacrifices to Daniel after he worships him.

Comment: That is your understanding but some modern versions beg to differ.  See eg, NIV.  Further, v47 makes it clear that Nebuchadnezzar recognised Daniel's God and the supreme God and honoured Daniel as God's representative.